# How to mark rational points on a sphere

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, image-processing

I found this [picture](http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/images/sphere1.gif) on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/178264), which I find very intriguing and so I like to know how to draw such an image with a simple computer program.

To calculate the rational point, I can draw a line from P_0(0,0,1) and P_1(u,v,0) and calculate the intersection with the sphere as follows:

\begin{equation}
x=\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1};y=\frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1};z=\frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1}
\end{equation}

So the intersection coordinates are rational numbers where

\begin{equation}
a=2u;b=2v;c=u^2+v^2-1;d=u^2+v^2+1
\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2
\end{equation}

If I understand correctly the guy who posted the picture he would mark the points depending on the value of d. So a value of d below a certain threshold would override the pixel color to white.

Now inside a program we would loop through all pixels along the x and y axis using the following algorithm:

```
for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        // does pixel ray intersect with sphere?
        // using orthgraphic projection ( all rays are parallel ) of 
        // sphere with radius of image height
        if(intersect(sphere,x,y))
        {
            // calculate the distance of the intersection of 
            // pixel ray and sphere
            double z = calc_distance(sphere,x,y);

            // the further away the darker the color
            rgb_color color = make_color(z);

            // calculate d
            // the gcd of a,b,c,d will be used to make d as small as possible
            int d = calculate_denominator(x,y)

            // 100 is made up
            if(d < 100)
            {
                color = white;
            }

            set_pixel(img,x,y,color);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help in correcting my algorithm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd iterate over $u$ and $v$ instead, since the point which actually has easy rational coordinates is not *exactly* at a pixel position.

```
double d;
for (int u = 0; u <= 100; ++u) {
  for (int v = 0; (d = u*u+v*v+1) <= 100; ++v) {
    markBlack(2*u/d, 2*v/d); // arguments are double in [0,1]
  }
}
```

or, if you want to stay in integer arithmetic:

```
int d;
for (int u = 0; u <= 100; ++u) {
  for (int v = 0; (d = u*u+v*v+1) <= 100; ++v) {
    int dh = d/2; // rounded down
    int x = (size*2*u + dh)/d;
    int y = (size*2*v + dh)/d;
    set_pixel(img,x,y,black);
  }
}
```

In both cases, I'm ommitting the third coordinate since we are projecting onto a coordinate plane.

The picture still doesn't look like the one you indicated, though. That's likely because you'd have to consider fractional $u,v$ as well. You might be better off using [Pythagorean quadruples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple) instead. Then you can use nested loops there.

```
int size = 2047, limit = 100;
int dm, dn, dp, d;
for (int m = 0; (dm = m*m) <= limit; ++m)
  for (int n = 0; (dn = dm + n*n) <= limit; ++n)
    for (int p = 0; (dp = dn + p*p) <= limit; ++p)
      for (int q = 0; (d = (dp + q*q) <= limit; ++q) {
        if (d == 0) continue;
        int a = abs(m*m + n*n - p*p - q*q);
        int b =     2*(m*q + n*p) ;
        int c = abs(2*(n*q - m*p));
        int dh = d/2;
        int x = (size*a + dh)/d;
        int y = (size*b + dh)/d;
        int z = (size*c + dh)/d;
        set_pixel(img,x,y,black);
        set_pixel(img,x,z,black);
        set_pixel(img,y,x,black);
        set_pixel(img,y,z,black);
        set_pixel(img,z,x,black);
        set_pixel(img,z,y,black);
      }
```

However, instead of marking pixels either black or white, you might also consider marking them with a suitable gray level, with the gray value depending on the number of rational points within a given pixel. If you do that, then you want to make sure that you mark every rational point exactly once. I did so in [the code used for the animation below](https://gist.github.com/gagern/34de9969abd8ebd031c8), building on [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2312125).

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Once I understand it I'll mark your answer. Could you post the whole code so I can test it out? I tried the the second loop but don't know what size means.

Comment: @chhenning: `size` is the size of the image, in pixels, Actually one less, since coordinates range from `0` to `size` inclusive. I never ran this C code, but I ran its Python analog in sage, and posted that [here](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/24014/single-pixel-marks-in-a-scatter_plot/).